# Passar parametro no onItemClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-adapter

Estou com dificuldade para passar o parâmetro dentro da repetição for no Android Studio. Ele lista os dados vindos do mysql, mas não consigo passar o paramêtro pra acessar o item.

```
for (int i=0; i<=ja.length(); i++){
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            numChamado[i] = jo.getString("numChamado");
            nomeCliente[i] = jo.getString("nomeCliente");
            logradouro[i] = jo.getString("logradouro");
            nome[i] = jo.getString("nome");
            processo[i] = jo.getString("processo");
            cidade[i] = jo.getString("cidade");


            lstData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DescItem.class);
                    intent.putExtra("numChamado",numChamado[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("nomeCliente",nomeCliente[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("logradouro",logradouro[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("processo", processo[i]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri, era mais fácil do que eu pensava! Basta passar o `[position]` no lugar do `[i]`